# telerik ajax ASP visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm update telerik asp.net ajax to(2019_1_215) in visual studio(2019) and I have a problem

**Error Creating control..failed to create designer**

[image: Screen Shot]

In telerik support page, they say that I have to replace the files in bin folder of project,but when I did these,I faced a new problem

'Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2019.1.211.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*********' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the Telerik.Web.UI.dll and the Telerik.Web.Design.dll are from the same installation and they have the same version.

After that add references to both dlls in the ASP.NET Web Forms application in Visual Studio and rebuild the app.

Comment: thank you 
i tried it, but I have see the same errorو
I avoided it the other way